# What is the benefit of multiple public ip's on a server

Tags: sql-server

I have developed an app which talks to a sql database on a server. I have just arranged with a server company to host my sql database and in setting it up have asked how many public ip's do i need.

The application will be used by 10/20 companies each having approx 10-20 ipads / android tablets. There will also be a website they can log onto to again look at the data on the server.

How many public ip's would i require, or what factors do i need to consider when deciding.

I should add if you haven't already worked it out, know nothing about servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ip address wouldn't matter that much if you don't need them. When will you need them?

1. When you want to add an extra layer of separation between companies (each its own ip)
2. More ip addresses means more DIFFERENT connections (so failover)
3. More ip addresses means more SIMULTANEOUS connections (so more possible users)
4. You want to have extra maintenance ;)

Just to mention a few